# A problem of Initial Value.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For $\lambda \in \mathbb R $,
 the **I.V.P** $\frac{dy}{dx} = \lambda \sin(x+y(x))$, with $y(0) = 1$ has

- No solution in any neighborhood of $0$.
- No solution in $\mathbb R $ if $| \lambda|\ \lt 1$.
- A solution in a neighborhood of $0$.
- A solution in $\mathbb R $ only if $| \lambda |\gt 1$.

How to proceed and solve it ? Any insight .

Thanks.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a multiple choice? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it's a mcq

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck? What is unclear to you, specifically?

Comment: Firstly I checked the criterion of existence and uniqueness theorem,and here f(x,y) is continuous,so a solution exist.Now for uniqueness I have to check the Lipschitz Condition,where I got stuck.

Comment: I don't think you really need to show uniqueness here. (if you still want to show the Lipschitz-continuity of the r.h.s and are stuck there, you might want to open a new question).

Comment: Ok , then What's the answer ? It has a solution in a neighborhood of 0 ?

Comment: Is there any information on $x$? Does the problem assume whether $x$ lies in a bounded interval, or $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Sorry ! I didn't get the hint , will you elaborate please?

Comment: Actually no restriction given on $ x$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Picard-Lindelöf Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) there exists a solution in a neighborhood of $0$ if the right hand side is continuous in $x$ and uniformly Lipschity in $y$. Here, the right hand side is $f(x,y) = \lambda \sin(x+y)$. Note that in the formulation of the theorem, when checking for continuity w.r.t. $x$, $y$ is viewed as a variable, and not as a function of $x$ (even though it depends on $x$ in the full ODE). The theorem requires assumptions on the r.h.s. *function* $f$, not on the r.h.s. of the ODE! Since we do not know anything about the solution $y(x)$ a priori, it doesn't make sense to check for continuity of $x\mapsto f(x, y(x))$, only for $x\mapsto f(x,y)$.

You mentioned that you have already shown continuity of $f$ w.r.t. $x$. It remains to show uniform Lipschitz continuity w.r.t. $y$, uniform in $x$. Recall that the global Lipschitz constant of a differentiable function is the supremum of the modulus of the first derivative, i.e. here:
$$L = \sup_{y\in\mathbb R}\Big|\frac{d}{dy} f(x,y)\Big| = \sup_{y\in\mathbb R}|\lambda\cos(x+y) | = |\lambda|.$$
So $|\lambda|$ is a Lipschitz constant of $f$ w.r.t. $y$, and since it is independent of $x$, it is uniform. Hence, we have shown that the assumptions of the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem are fulfilled, and therefore we know that the ODE has a solution for $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

A solution exists for any choice of $\lambda$, so the other options are indeed false.

*Additional remark:* It is not much additional work to see that a solution is global (i.e. exists for all $x>0$). From the ODE we immediately find that $|y'|\le |\lambda|$, i.e. a solution never grows or falls at a rate greater than $|\lambda|$. Therefore a solution with IC $y(0) = 1$ will always stay between the functions $1+|\lambda|x$ and $1-|\lambda| x$ for $x>0$. This is equivalent to $y|y(x)-1|\le |\lambda |x$. Now we observe that a solution of an ODE satisfying the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem is not global iff it becomes unbounded (i.e. it blows up) in finite time (see the [detailed proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Detailed_proof) for more details). But with the above trick we have seen that this cannot happen - it stays bounded (even though the bound grows; but it is enough to prevent a blow-up). Therefore any solution is global. However, this is not nedded for the solution of your problem.

Comment: So there is no restriction on $\lambda$ ?

Comment: So third option is right ?

Comment: 1 more question, how did you get the bound condition ? I can't get that ..@DominikS

Comment: But y is always a function of x ,I think ..

Comment: But not when checking the conditions of the theorem - see my edit in the first paragraph.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me, even the justifications also..but is  your pre edit version wrong then ? I didn't get the bound condition there ?

Comment: the first version was not correct. However the estimate was, I have added it to my answer. But it is not needed for the solution.

Comment: Oh ! Now it is clear..Thanks ,hope it will help me in near future...thanks a lot for your answer..

Comment: You said that a solution exists for any choice of $\lambda $ , but shouldn't it be bounded ? Because as we know that if f(x,y) be such that its partial derivative w.r.t to y is bounded in a certain domain D,then f satisfies Lipschitz Condition..So if it is unbounded then no conclusion can be made.. further here $\lambda $ is the Lipschitz Constant,which is equal to the lub of all values of the partial derivative of f(x,y) w.r.t y while y varies in D. What do you think ? @DominikS

Comment: You can in principle choose any value for $\lambda$ you like. But it is still a constant. It does not change during the analysis. (1) you fix $\lambda$ and (2) you make the analysis. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think yes..@DomimikS